# Will XAMPP developed PHP site work on IIS server?

Tags: php, iis, xampp

I am currently developing a Joomla PHP website on my XAMPP server. My client just said he is running an Windows IIS server with PHP and MySQL installed. Im wondering will my XAMPP devleoped site work on his server or do I have to develop my site on a an IIS server? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP server is not really a server it  a "free and open source cross-platform web server solution stack package, consisting mainly of the Apache HTTP Server, MySQL database, and interpreters for scripts written in the PHP and Perl programming languages." by wiki  if your client is running the IIS version 6.0 or 7.0 you can easliy install the FastCGI with PHP Manager for IIS7 plus i belive there is verion installer of joomla that made specifically to run on iis.
http://php.iis.net/

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/install-joomla-on-iis

Answer (score 0):

It should work on IIS provided IIS is handling php scripts and the versions of PHP on your XAMPP and clients IIS are preferably same..